# How edit/change View from layout in RemoteView or create RemoteView from View?

Tags: java, android, widget

I create widget for Android application (in Java, of course). I have classic RemoteViews created from layout (using layout id)

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.view);
```

and I need edit or change view (identify by id). In classic View is it easy, using findViewById function.

```
View v = ... //inflate layout R.layout.view
View my = v.findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
processView(my); //filling view
```

But it is not supported in RemoteViews. Is possible get view using apply(), but after processView and reapply() I not see changes in view.

```
View v = rv.apply(context, null);
View my = v.findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
processView(my); //this work's fine
rv.reapply(context,my);
```

Second, worse option, is get my required view form RemoteViews, process it, delete old view and add processed new view using addView().

```
RemoteViews rv = ...
View my = ... //apply, find and process
//remove old view
RemoteViews rvMy = ... //create RemoteViews from View
rv.addView(rvMy)
```

But I don't know how create RemoteViews from View (it is possible?). Any ideas how solve this problem?

Comment: I think your question need a bit of clarification. Are you trying to change text of RemoteViews views without knowing its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because edit/change (sub)view from removeview or creating remoteview from view is propably not possible (on base information which I founded) I solved my problem using **naming** necessery view (most ofen textview), geting views id using his names and reflection and process in cycle. For naming is possible to use bash, python, or anything else.

Example:

```
RemoteView rv = ...

/* 
exemplary rv layout:
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|tv0x0|tv0x1|tv0x2|tv0x3|tv0x4|tv0x5|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|tv1x0|tv1x1|tv1x2|tv1x3|tv1x4|tv1x5|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
*/

String prefix = "tv";
for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
        // use reflection, searched in stackoverflow
        int id = getItemIdFromName(prefix+i+"x"+j); 
        // working with concrete id using RemoteView set functions, e.g
        rv.setTextViewText(id, String.ValueOf(i);
    }
}
```

This way is possible process a large number of views and apply remoteview function for them.

Answer (score 7):

Try this way :

```
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, text); <---- here you can set text

        // Tell the widget manager
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
```

Here is a useful post to understand widget behaviour :

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. This method (and other set*) for setting properties of the RemoteViews object I know. Problem is, than I must know all ID's and set each of them separately (in widget and also in layout) - it is possible, but isn't good! For example: now i have a layout with defined structure. When I want filled them I put him into presenter method (present(View v)) and it's all! Possible solution maybe is set ID's in layout and using reflection to iterate and process them. If not better options! [I hope this is understandable.]